# Linq to SQL exception handler?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there some property that I can use to track all exceptions in datacontext?
This is really useful when you work with stored procedures - you don't know when and where it fail to execute.

Is there a better way than wrapping eveything with facade class?

**UPD:** 
The reason I asking this, is because I'm working with legacy code. Context is used everywhere, and if I want to log something more about exception, for example - query with all its parameters, I need to wrap into try/catch a TON of code.

Also, I don't want to log every query in contex, this is just stupid and put a bunch of overhead.

Comment: Is this an application or web application?

Comment: How would it be helpful? If you call multiple stored procedures from your code, you get the exception as soon as one of them fails. If you call one stored procedure that calls many others, you still get only one exception. What would you expect to do with the exceptions anyway, except handle them in the code they occur, ie in C# or T-SQL?

Comment: What do you mean "you don't know when and where it fail to execute" ? How are you using stored procedures?

Comment: Instead of assuming the "legacy" code is broken, consider that you may be about to break the application. If a data exception occurs, you stop and handle it or log it at the highest level possible. You don't need to put exception handling at the lowest level just to log something and rethrow. If you have a business method called `Transfer1MillionDollars()`, the proper place to handle errors is there, not 3 levels down in the data layer

Comment: If I want to log something generaly for all contexts why I should avoid it? This is just not smart to not log very useful for debug information. If your function throws exception on specific input - you will just spend a lot of time and in bad case will wait for it to occure again.